# How to pass the id of the html button to python file by using django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have the following code in my HTML file that is to created the dynamic button.

```
  {% for i in loop_times %}
 <button type="submit" class="'btn btn-lg" name="{{ i }}" id="{{ i }}" onclick="alert(this.id)" formmethod="post"><a href="{% url 'button' %}">{{i|safe}}</a></button><br><br>
  {% endfor %}
```

This button has the url link which link to urls.py:

```
  url(r'^button',views.data, name='button'),
```

The id of this buttons will dynamically created based on hw many product I have and now I want get the id of the particular buttons to pass to the python file in order for me to used the id to do analysis, so I have the following code in my view.py file

```
 labelid = request.GET[("id", False)]
```

Anyone have idea on how to pass id of the dynamically buttons to my view.py, because above code not able to run, I'm very new to python and don't have any basic for my programing background hope that I can get some idea here, thanks

Comment: Where are you getting your error?

Comment: Hi @jape, the error is  'labelid = request.GET[("id", False)]'

MultiValueDictKeyError for '[("id", False)]'

Comment: You can set `value` attribute in html to pass the value of that button. Are these buttons within `<form>` tag?

Comment: @Rohan not in the <form> tag but how to set value attribute? can give me some idea? because I not able imagine that

Comment: Can you please update you question with full HTML of form?

Comment: ` <div>
                        {% for i in loop_times %}
                            <button type="submit" class="'btn btn-lg" name="{{ i }}" id="{{ i }}" onclick="alert(this.id)" formmethod="post"><a href="{% url 'button' %}?id={{ i }}">{{i|safe}}</a></button><br><br>

                        {% endfor %}


            </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
labelid = request.GET.get("id", False)
```

instead of this:

```
labelid = request.GET[("id", False)]
```

Your current method is trying to get `("id", False)` as a dictionary value, but obviously that's not what you are trying to do.

The way I suggested will look for value `id`. If it cannot find it, then `labelid` will be set to `False`.